# Rowset does not support scrolling backward

Tags: sql, vbscript, recordset, rowset

I am trying to query a MySQL database with the below code:

```vb
'declare the variables 
Dim Connection
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
SQL = "SELECT * FROM CUSIP"

'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'open the connection to the database
Connection.Open "DSN=CCS_DSN;UID=root;PWD=password;Database=CCS"

Recordset.CursorType=adOpenDynamic

'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 

Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
Recordset.MoveFirst

If Recordset.Find ("CUSIP_NAME='somevalue'") Then
    MsgBox "Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Not Found"
End If


'close the connection and recordset objects to free up resources
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing
```

Whenever I execute the above I get an error 'rowset does not support scrolling backward', any suggestions?

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275542%28v=bts.10%29.aspx you don't use .Find correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`adOpenDynamic` is not declared in VBScript and therefore equals `Empty`, which gets converted to `0` when you assign the `CursorType` property.
`0` is `adOpenForwardOnly`, and forward only does not support moving backwards, an ability the `Find` method wants.

You should replace `adOpenDynamic` with its literal value:

```vb
Recordset.CursorType = 2 'adOpenDynamic
```

To avoid this class of errors altogether, place `Option Explicit` as the first line of your script.

Comment: That did the trick ! Thanks !! btw would you know why 'recordset.recordcount' returns -1 when there are 5 rows in the database and cursortype changed to dynamic ?

Comment: @TelsonAlva Because it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx) to do so: `The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.`

Comment: Oh, i understand now ! So i need to change the cursor type to static in order to get the count. Otherwise since it is dynamic there are possibilities for the record to change dynamically. Thanks !

Comment: One last question, my Find statement is not returning a match. Any reasons ? i have set the exact string which is under the coloum CUSIP_NAME but still i get 'Not Found'

Comment: @TelsonAlva Because, as Ekkehard.Horner [noted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122308/rowset-does-not-support-scrolling-backward#comment19548549_14122308), you're not using `Find` properly. It's a sub and it does not return a value. It moves to a record. If it doesn't find one, `.EOF` becomes `true`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the rowset does not permit backward moves; as the error message suggests. Your code is not using them; so you should replace the line

Recordset.CursorType=adOpenDynamic
with 
Recordset.CursorType=adOpenForwardOnly (or the equivalent value 0)

Better leave the line altogether; the default is forward cursor.

Comment: You got it the other way round. The `Find` method wants ability to move backwards.