# VBA "rowset does not support fetching backward" error with .cursertype adjusted

Tags: vba, excel

Using the following code I open a connection with SQL server and drop the results straight into an array.  My problem is that I get an error for the rowcount, which I need to redim my array.  The error I get is on the line indicated below and reads

> "rowset does not support fetching backward"

All answers I can find suggest the cursor type as the problem, but I have changed this as far as I can tell.  Apologies for the long code, I felt it best to leave the start in.

```
Function ConnectServer() As String()
'Working SQL Server connection

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim strSqlQuery As String
Dim iCols As Long


' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=wait;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=what;" & _
              "User Id=foo;" & _
              "Password=bar;"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conn.CommandTimeout = 50

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString

'    Debug.Print strSqlQuery
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM b")

' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
'*****************Problem here********************
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

'Read into array and cleanup...
End If

End Function
```

I don't believe this to be a duplicate of this question:

[Rowset does not support scrolling backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122308/rowset-does-not-support-scrolling-backward)

Because I already incorporated the answer into my code and the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you adding all the records to an array?

Comment: Yep, I need to count the records to redim the array, then i will add them in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by using conn.Execute to fill the recordset.  Setting the recordset's activeconnection to the ADODB.Connection and using the recordset's open method will fix the issue.

```
Function ConnectServer() As String()
   'Working SQL Server connection

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim strSqlQuery As String
    Dim iCols As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=wait;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=what;" & _
                  "User Id=foo;" & _
                  "Password=bar;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = sConnString
    conn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM b"
        .Open
    End With

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then

        rs.MoveLast
        Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

        'Read into array and cleanup...
    End If

End Function
```

You can use Recordset.GetRows() to fill the array.  No need to dim it. [GetRows Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I have a complex union in the `source` part of recordset and this method doesn't appear to work for me. Same exact declaration and everything. Also P.S. `GetRows()` is great, until your dataset is huge. Sadly, my dataset is outside the range where GetRows() works.