# Converting VBA to VBScript - Not working but no error

Tags: vba, t-sql, vbscript, adodb

I've been following articles and questions about converting VBA to VBScript but I'm now stuck. The following code still works in VBA (if I remove the Sub routine call) but it won't run as a script.

The code opens a connection to SQL Server to check a table to see if the process has already run today and loads the result into a Recordset. If the field is set to `No` then it opens up an Excel workbook and runs a macro. It works in VBA but when I run the same code as a script nothing happens (no errors either).

Can you see what the problem is? Thanks very much.

NB. There are two lines for `cmd.CommandText`. The commented out line is designed to always return `No` for testing purposes only.

```vb
' Author Steve Wolstencroft
' Inititates the Automated Excel Refresh Procedure
Option Explicit

Pivot_Refresh

Public Function ConnectToSQLDwarfP()
    On Error Resume Next
    ConnectToSQLDwarfP = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=DwarfP;Database=DwarfPortable;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
End Function

Public Sub Pivot_Refresh()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim cnx
    Dim Rst

    Set cnx = New ADODB.Connection
        cnx.ConnectionString = ConnectToSQLDwarfP
        cnx.Open

    Dim cmd

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Case When max(DwarfPortable.dbo.fn_GetJustDate(pl.StartDateTime)) = DwarfPortable.dbo.fn_GetJustDate(getDate()) Then 'Y'  Else 'N' End as RunToday From ProcessControl.dbo.ProcessLog pl Where pl.ProcessName = 'Excel_Auto_Refresh'"
        'cmd.CommandText = "Select Case When max(pl.StartDateTime) = DwarfPortable.dbo.fn_GetJustDate(getDate()) Then 'Y' Else 'N' End as RunToday From ProcessControl.dbo.ProcessLog pl Where pl.ProcessName = 'Excel_Auto_Refresh'"

    Set Rst = cmd.Execute

    Dim objXL, objBook
    Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    If Rst.Fields("RunToday") = "N" Then
        Set objBook = objXL.Workbooks.Open("\\nch\dfs\SharedArea\HI\Clinical-Informatics\InfoRequestOutputs\Regular-Jobs\Pivot-Refresh\Pivot-Refresh-Control.xls", 0, True)
        objXL.Application.Visible = True

        objXL.Application.Run "'Pivot-Refresh-Control.xls'!Auto_Refresh"

        objXL.ActiveWindow.Close
        objXL.Quit

        Set objBook = Nothing
        Set objXL = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks GSerg. That's great. It's now working, I didn't realise CreateObject should also be used with ADODb - makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate external objects in VBScript with e.g. `New ADODB.Connection` because there are no references to external libraries.

You [can't use constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14122422/11683) like `adCmdText` either. They will be treated as undefined empty variables.

You don't get any errors because you shut them up with `On Error Resume Next`. Remove that and you will get your errors.

Make sure all external object instantiation is done with `CreateObject` like you are doing for Excel, and replace all external constants with their literal values.

Comment: Thanks for that. My first VBScript is now working. I'll remember that in future.