# Recordset.Find Error: Rowset does not support scrolling backward with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures, adodb

I am trying to find values in my recordset with `Find` as `Seek` does not seem to be supported, but I can't get past the error

> Rowset does not support scrolling backward

According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122308/rowset-does-not-support-scrolling-backward), I have to specify `adOpenDynamic`, but this did not change the error code.

I am using a stored procedure (`sp_fkeys`), which returns all keys for all tables, and in this case for one table as I specify the table name.

```vb
Private Sub maintablebox_Change()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim keys As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
connstring = "omitted"
cnn.Open connstring

Set keys = New ADODB.Recordset
keys.CursorLocation = adUseServer
query = "EXEC sp_fkeys @fktable_name = 'astAssets'"
keys.Open query, connstring, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

' >>>>>Error on the line below
keys.Find "PKTABLE_NAME = 'astAssetTypes'"

Debug.Print keys.Fields("FKCOLUMN_NAME")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies not in the `keys.CursorType` statement, but in the `keys.CursorLocation` statement.

I replaced `keys.CursorLocation = adUseServer` with `keys.CursorLocation = adUseClient`, which immediately resolved the issue.

The working code has become

```vb
Private Sub maintablebox_Change()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim keys As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
connstring = "omitted"
cnn.Open connstring

Set keys = New ADODB.Recordset
keys.CursorLocation = adUseClient
query = "EXEC sp_fkeys @fktable_name = 'astAssets'"
keys.Open query, connstring, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

keys.Find "PKTABLE_NAME = 'astAssetTypes'"

Debug.Print keys.Fields("FKCOLUMN_NAME")
End Sub
```

I found the solution on [this vbforums thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?435384-RESOLVED-rowset-does-not-support-scrolling-backward). I noticed the OP using a stored procedure just like I am, so the error code I was presented with may be due to that factor.

I have only limited knowledge of ADODB recordsets, so if someone would be willing to explain why setting the cursorlocation to adUseClient fixed my problem, please be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and could reproduce the error. For me it was solved by adding an moveFirst.

```vb
Private Sub maintablebox_Change()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim keys As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set keys = New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open DBPORT

Set keys.ActiveConnection = cnn
keys.CursorType = adOpenStatic

keys.Open "Select city_name, afas_rel_number, city_code from pkn_cities where has_month_report = true order by city_name ASC;"

keys.MoveFirst 'this did the trick for me
keys.Find "city_code = '1366'"
Debug.Print keys.Fields("city_name")

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't the CursorType be overruled later by `adOpenDynamic` in the `keys.Open` statement?

Comment: Going to answer my own question and say that it indeed does. Regardless, setting the cursor type to `adOpenStatic` works neither in the `keys.Open` statement nor by setting it right after `Set keys = New ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. This is some code I used in the past as an example. [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/find-method-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: No change, unfortunately. `keys.MoveLast` does not work either: "Rowset does not support fetching backward"

Comment: I did play around with `MoveFirst` before starting this thread. Seeing as how it did work for you, I am attributing the error to the stored procedure