# How verify if a data exist in a recordset with an external variable? VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to verify if the value of a specific variable (oLookFullName) exist in this recordset and if it isn't the case I would like to print a message, so I tried this:

```
rs.MoveFirst

filter2 = "[Nom] = " & oLookFullName
rs.Find filter2
If (rs.BOF = True) Or (rs.EOF = True) Then
    Debug.Print oLookFullName & " is not find"
End If
```

But I have this error at the line `rs.Find filter2`:

```
Run-time error 3001 Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DAO, try with:

```vb
filter2 = "[Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "'"
rs.FindFirst filter2
If rs.NoMatch Then
    Debug.Print oLookFullName & " is not found."
End If
```

For ADO, try with:

```vb
filter2 = "[Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "'"
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Find filter2
If rs.EOF Then
    Debug.Print oLookFullName & " is not found."
End If
```

Comment: Vba compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: I was writing it to you ... really sorry

Comment: Run-time error '-2147217879 (80040e29)': rowset does not support scrolling backward. On the line `rs.Find filter2`

Comment: You may have to first set the current row - [Find Method (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/find-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: You need a different cursor type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122308/rowset-does-not-support-scrolling-backward

Comment: How can I add one more criteria in filter2 ? Because I have an error :
filter2 = "[Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "'" And "[nomEntreprise] = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"

Comment: You can't. You'll have to use some work-around for that.